# Python Post Request works but not curl

Tags: python, curl

I can't seem to get curl to work for an API call however, python works fine.  The options in my curl requests are correct.  It has to do with the post data where something screwy is going on.

My Python request is:

```
requests.post("https://example.com", data={"my_id":"2o3i234j", verify=False}).json();
```

My Curl response works fine, however I get a response from the API saying I have not sent in a value for my_id.

I'm using this as a parameter:

```
curl -k -X POST -d "{'my_id':'2o3i234j'}" https://abcd.com
```

Comment: You're trying to use the Python dictionary syntax with curl's `-d` option which makes no sense. Please consult the `curl(1)` man page.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm confused.  It's just name value pairs.  Whats the equivalent in sending this in curl then?

Comment: `{ ... }` is Python dictionary syntax, and makes no sense to curl. [mescalinum's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31127158/119527) shows the correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a  post  chunk  that
>                 looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

The format however is key=value.

```
curl -d "my_id=2o3i234j" https://abcd.com
```